# How to upload image in ionic 4/5 using backend PHP?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to upload an image, for this, my backend developer give me the JSON demo of the postman and he was asking add image as Multipart form data.

First as he said Multipart form data so I send him like [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480171/how-to-convert-camera-image-to-blob-in-ionic-5/61482201?noredirect=1#comment108819985_61482201) but now he said not this.

Here is my postman profile update screen

[image]

the image above image key avatar and value is profile picture.
please help me...

Answer (score 0):

```
async uploadImageData(formData: FormData) {

    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({

        message: 'Uploading image...',

    });

    await loading.present();

 

    this.http.post("http://localhost:8888/upload.php", formData)

        .pipe(

            finalize(() => {

                loading.dismiss();

            })

        )

        .subscribe(res => {

            if (res['success']) {

                this.presentToast('File upload complete.')

            } else {

                this.presentToast('File upload failed.')

            }

        });

}
```

This is the upload code , and for full code, its from this reference : 
https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-image-upload-storage/